# Configure DataSource programmatically in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, datasource

With Spring Boot I can instantiate a `JdbcTemplate` with the following:

Code:

```
@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
```

Properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://my_url:my_port/my_other_stuff
spring.datasource.username=my_user_name
spring.datasource.password=my_password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
```

This create a DataSource of class: `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource`

How do I set the DataSource username/password programmatically?

We have a policy not to store credentials in plain text and I have to use a specific credential provider where I work.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You can use `DataSourceBuilder` if you are using `jdbc` starter. Also, in order to override the default autoconfiguration bean you need to mark your bean as a `@Primary`

In my case I have properties starting with `datasource.postgres` prefix.

E.g

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.postgres")
@Bean
@Primary
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder
        .create()
        .build();
}
```

If it is not feasible for you, then you can use

```
@Bean
@Primary
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder
        .create()
        .username("")
        .password("")
        .url("")
        .driverClassName("")
        .build();
}
```

Comment: @Primary is not necessary, since the AutoConfiguration only creates a DataSource bean, when no other bean is defined.

Comment: create() should probably be first

Comment: Primary not required. @Bean enables Spring boot to register configuration. driver class name, url, user, pwd required

Comment: As per the JavaDoc @Primary "Indicates that a bean should be given preference when multiple candidates are qualified to autowire a single-valued dependency." https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html

Comment: But how about set `spring.datasource.validation-query` and `spring.datasource.test-while-idle` and `spring.datasource.time-between-eviction-runs-millis`

Comment: I also have the same question - How to set "spring.datasource.validation-query" in multi tenancy project where we are creating DataSource at runtime using DataSourceBuilder.create().

Comment: how to do this same thing with different datasources for junit/local server/dev server

Comment: Can I combine `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation with programmatic settings on the DataSourceBuilder?. I want to configure test-on-borrow and eviction runs, but there is no option in the builder to set those values.

Answer (score 26):

My project of spring-boot has run normally according to your assistance.  The yaml datasource configuration is:

```
spring:
  # (DataSourceAutoConfiguration & DataSourceProperties)
  datasource:
    name: ds-h2
    url: jdbc:h2:D:/work/workspace/fdata;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false
    username: h2
    password: h2
    driver-class: org.h2.Driver
```

**Custom DataSource**

```java
@Configuration
@Component
public class DataSourceBean {

    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder
                .create()
//                .url("jdbc:h2:D:/work/workspace/fork/gs-serving-web-content/initial/data/fdata;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false")
//                .username("h2")
//                .password("h2")
//                .driverClassName("org.h2.Driver")
                .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer helps because it shows how to use the default spring.datasource properties to define the DataSource. Note that if you want to override only the password, say, then you would need to remove the password definition from application.properties (or application.yml) and set that one property in the code.

Comment: @Willie Wheeler Are you sure that would work? Because what I understand the above code will return an entirely new datasource bean. Meaning the spring.datasource properties wont take effect, and will be replaced by the new bean.

Comment: Yeah, I've used this approach to externalize passwords into Vault.

Comment: @WillieWheeler You are right. I just tried and it works.

Comment: Good to hear @FadhlieIkram. Thanks for checking.

Answer (score 16):

All you need to do is annotate a method that returns a DataSource with @Bean.
A complete working example follows.

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
        dataSourceBuilder.url(dbUrl);
        dataSourceBuilder.username(username);
        dataSourceBuilder.password(password);
        return dataSourceBuilder.build();   
}
```

Answer (score 15):

If you're using latest spring boot (with jdbc starter and Hikari) you'll run into:
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: jdbcUrl is required with driverClassName.`
To solve this:

1. In your application.properties:

`datasource.oracle.url=youroracleurl`

2. In your application define as bean (**`@Primary` is mandatory!**):

```
@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties("datasource.oracle")
public DataSourceProperties getDatasourceProperties() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("datasource.oracle")
public DataSource getDatasource() {
    return getDatasourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder()
           .username("username")
           .password("password")
           .build();
}
```

Comment: I also had to declare the DataSource bean as @Primary.

Comment: There is a simpler way: in the application properties (i.e. applicaiotion.yml) rename:
`spring.datasource.url` to `spring.datasource.jdbc-url`.
This should do the trick!!! (It did in my case - SpringBoot v2.3.2)

Comment: @DavideMartorana I thought that this trick but I'm assuming it won't be integrated with classes lik HikariConfig (so it needs code change to update Hikari config)

Answer (score 5):

If you want more datesource configs e.g.

```
spring.datasource.test-while-idle=true 
spring.datasource.time-between-eviction-runs-millis=30000
spring.datasource.validation-query=select 1
```

you could use below code

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DataSource dataSource = new DataSource(); // org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource;
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
    dataSource.setUrl(url);
    dataSource.setUsername(username);
    dataSource.setPassword(password);
    dataSource.setTestWhileIdle(testWhileIdle);     
    dataSource.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(timeBetweenEvictionRunsMills);
    dataSource.setValidationQuery(validationQuery);
    return dataSource;
}
```

refer: [Spring boot jdbc Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29729909/spring-boot-jdbc-connection)

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative way you can use DriverManagerDataSource such as:

```
public DataSource getDataSource(DBInfo db) {

    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

    dataSource.setUsername(db.getUsername());
    dataSource.setPassword(db.getPassword());
    dataSource.setUrl(db.getUrl());
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(db.getDriverClassName());

    return dataSource;
}
```

However be careful about using it, because:

> NOTE: This class is not an actual connection pool; it does not
>   actually pool Connections. It just serves as simple replacement for a
>   full-blown connection pool, implementing the same standard interface,
>   but creating new Connections on every call. [reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DriverManagerDataSource.html)

Comment: `NOTE: Within special class loading environments such as OSGi, this class is effectively superseded by SimpleDriverDataSource due to general class loading issues with the JDBC DriverManager that be resolved through direct Driver usage (which is exactly what SimpleDriverDataSource does).`

Answer (score 2):

for springboot 2.1.7 working with url seems not to work. change with jdbcUrl instead.

In properties:

```
security:
      datasource:
        jdbcUrl: jdbc:mysql://ip:3306/security
        username: user
        password: pass
```

In java:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "security.datasource")
@Bean("dataSource")
@Primary
public DataSource dataSource(){

    return DataSourceBuilder
            .create()
            .build();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I customized *Tomcat DataSource* in *Spring-Boot 2*.

Dependency versions:

- *spring-boot: 2.1.9.RELEASE*
- *tomcat-jdbc: 9.0.20*

May be it will be useful for somebody.

**application.yml**

```
spring:
    datasource:
        driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
        type: org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource
        url: jdbc:postgresql://${spring.datasource.database.host}:${spring.datasource.database.port}/${spring.datasource.database.name}
        database:
            host: localhost
            port: 5432
            name: rostelecom
        username: postgres
        password: postgres
        tomcat:
            validation-query: SELECT 1
            validation-interval: 30000           
            test-on-borrow: true
            remove-abandoned: true
            remove-abandoned-timeout: 480
            test-while-idle: true
            time-between-eviction-runs-millis: 60000
            log-validation-errors: true
            log-abandoned: true
```

**Java**

```java
@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.tomcat")
public PoolConfiguration postgresDataSourceProperties() {
    return new PoolProperties();
}

@Bean(name = "primaryDataSource")
@Primary
@Qualifier("primaryDataSource")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
    PoolConfiguration properties = postgresDataSourceProperties();
    return new DataSource(properties);
}
```

The main reason why it had been done is several DataSources in application and one of them it is necessary to mark as a *@Primary*.