# Configure DataSourceBuilder url dynamically in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, datasource

I have the following properties defined in `application.properties` file.

```
sample.db.serverName=10.10.10.10
sample.db.serverPort=1234
sample.db.databaseName=sampleDb
```

Now I use the DataSourceBuilder, but I need to build the url with all the available information since it has only url parameter.

I am not sure how to read the properties into a POJO and get the handle in the DataSource class

```
public DataSource dataSource()
{
   //handle for POJO
   //StringBuilder to build the url
   return DataSourceBuilder.create.url(str.toString()).build();
}
```

P.S : I referred this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28821521/configure-datasource-programmatically-in-spring-boot), but it is different from my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create configuration properties class (simple POJO):

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "sample.db")
public class DbProperties {
    private String serverName;
    private String serverPort;
    private String databaseName;

    // getters and setters
}
```

After that you can tell Spring to create an instance of this class and fill properties from the properties file:

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties(value = DbProperties.class)
```

And finally you can autowire them into the method which creates datasource:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(value = DbProperties.class)
public class DatasourceConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(final DbProperties properties) {
        // do whatever you need
        return DataSourceBuilder.create.url(str.toString()).build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Annotate your method with `@Bean`, and pass the properties to it using `@Value` annotation:

```
@Value("${sample.db.serverName}") private String serverName;
// .. repeat for other properties ...
@Bean public DataSource dataSource() {
    String url = // build URL from serverName field and other fields
    // create DataSource instance and return it
}
```

You can also use `@Value` annotation with method parameters, not just fields - but then it starts to look complicated if you call your `dataSource()` method from code.